# Different height (and width?) of blocks (divs) in different browsers

Tags: css

Photo of my problem:

> [image]

First (from left to right) is Google chrome. Second is Opera. In all other browsers dimensions as in the Opera. Other sites are displayed equally.

["Reset CSS" from "Yahoo"](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). The same sh*t with the rest of my sites. They seem to be reduced proportionally in other browsers than Google Chrome (But the problem is not in Chrome, because the other sites (not mine) look exactly the same in all this browsers).

I apologize if my question is stupid, but I really don't understand how to solve this problem.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to your demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a few issues with this, and you frankly don't have enough here for us to help you all that much. Here are some general things to check:

1. **Make sure Chrome's not zoomed in.** If you look carefully, you'll see everything in Chrome is slightly larger. Ctrl+0 should ensure that it didn't get accidentally zoomed in.
2. **Make sure it's not a known thing with Chrome.** I saw mention about Chrome rendering things a little larger, that would probably be a good place to start. Don't rule out the possibility that it's not Chrome being stupid, just because you don't see it in other sites. They also probably look the same in IE 6-8, too, but if you take out all of the hoops required to get those sites that way, you'll probably find a pretty broken experience. There's no saying there weren't any hoops required to get Chrome to behave as expected.
3. **Use Chrome's developer tools to make sure the values you expect are what are *actually* being used.** Just because you think it's supposed to be 300px tall, and the text is 20px, it doesn't mean it actually *is* and there's not some weird inheritance glitch (or the CSS isn't loading properly).

Also, *it's okay for browsers to be slightly different.* I understand if you have a boss breathing down your neck about it, there's not much you can do. However, do keep that fact in mind when trying to troubleshoot stuff like this, or even when making design decisions. Sometimes, it's better than spending countless hours (which equate to lots of money in a business situation) for no real return. Think about this - how many users will *actually* have two browsers side by side and do a pixel-by-pixel comparison, or otherwise notice such differences (hell, for that matter, how many of your users even know what a browser *is*)?